# How to fix a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in a scala - maven project

Tags: maven, nosuchmethoderror, typesafe-config, maven-dependency, dependency-tree

error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImplUtil.toCamelCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
16:31:59    at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigBeanImpl.createInternal(ConfigBeanImpl.java:52)
16:31:59    at com.typesafe.config.ConfigBeanFactory.create(ConfigBeanFactory.java:47)
```

This is a multi module maven project which is calling a function from a dependency which is then calling typesafe.config.
I have already checked mvn dependency tree for the project and it only contains one version of typesafe.config once which is `1.3.4` (i also tried the latest version `1.4.3`, still seeing the same issue)

this was the only line containing typesafe.config in the dependency tree:

```
com.typesafe:config:jar:1.4.3:compile
```

there are also other typesafe dependencies present if its relevant:

```
+- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:jar:3.5.0:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:jar:2.5.32:compile
  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.8.0:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:jar:2.5.32:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-kafka_2.12:jar:1.0.5:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:jar:2.5.32:compile
  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-protobuf_2.12:jar:2.5.32:compile
  +- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
  \- com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.12:jar:0.3.8:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.12:jar:2.5.32:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http_2.12:jar:10.1.15:compile
  \- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-core_2.12:jar:10.1.15:compile
    \- com.typesafe.akka:akka-parsing_2.12:jar:10.1.15:compile
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-testkit_2.12:jar:2.5.32:test
+- com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-testkit_2.12:jar:10.1.15:test
```

What else can i check/do?

Comment: Last time I had a NoSuchMethodError it was on a project with many concurrently running programs calling each other remotely, and one of them did not get the update that included the new method. So: where is the code you are calling, and does it have a method with this name and signature?